# I can't create an user with cloud functions

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I tried using createUser but it just creates an anonymous user, so I tried createUserWithEmailAndPassword, but still doesn't work.

Here is the cloud function:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { onCall } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const { getAuth } = require("firebase-admin/auth");
const { setGlobalOptions } = require("firebase-functions/v2");
setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10 });

admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = onCall(async (request) => {
  await getAuth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(request.data.email, request.data.password)
.then((userCredential) => {
  if (userCredential) {
    logger.info("New User Created: " + userCredential.uid);
    getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(userCredential.uid, {
      admin: request.data.isAdmin,
    });
    getAuth()
      .updateUser(userCredential.uid, {
        displayName: request.data.displayName,
      })
      .then((userRecord) => {
        logger.info("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
      });

    return userCredential;
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
  return error;
});
});
```

Here is how I call it on my flutter app:

```
void registerUser() async {
final result =
    await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('createUser').call({
  "email": emailController.text,
  "password": passwordController.text,
  "displayName": userNameController.text,
  "isAdmin": isAdmin.value
});

print('function result: ' + result.data.toString());
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting(on my vscode console, not function logs):

```
Error: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL


dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
packages/cloud_functions_web/https_callable_web.dart 56:7                     call
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 60:31            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1666:54                                          runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 171:22                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 852:46                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 873:13                                    
_propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 649:5                                     [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 739:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               
_startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method exists only in the client-side SDK for JavaScript **clients**. You're importing the Admin SDK for use on trusted environments, where the call to [create a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) is `createUser`.

---

I find this type of mistake hard to troubleshoot on deployed Cloud Functions, so recommend taking one of these approaches:

- Use the [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to develop the Cloud Function. Not only will this show you the logging output in a much more easy to grok way, it also prevents you from accidentally messing up your real project.
- Develop the main code of the function as a [regular Node.js script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#node.js) first, and only adding a Cloud Functions wrapper once the basic code works.